# Enable DHE_RSA cipher suites on OS X/iOS

Tags: ios, macos, nsurlsession

I am developing an OS X app that communicates with a server over HTTPS using [`NSURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html) and [`dataTaskWithRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:). The server supports the following cipher-string: `kEDH+AESGCM:HIGH:MEDIUM:TLSv1:!kEECDH:!RC4:!3DES:!SEED:!IDEA:!RC2:!DES:!MD5:!DSS:!aNULL:!eNULL:!PSK:!SRP:!aECDH:!ECDSA`.

On OS X 10.11 I get the error message: `CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)`.

Quote from the [OS X 10.11 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/General/rn-osx-10.11/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016209-CH1-DontLinkElementID_16):

> DHE_RSA cipher suites are now disabled by default in Secure Transport for TLS clients. This may cause a failure to connect to TLS servers that only support DHE_RSA cipher suites. Applications that explicitly enable cipher suites using SSLSetEnabledCiphers() are not affected.

So the release notes talk about using `SSLSetEnabledCiphers()` but I can’t create a SSLContext and find Apples [Secure Transport Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/secureTransportRef/index.html) quite confusing (lots of deprecated stuff).

How can I re enable DHE_RSA cipher suites im my app? Swift or Objective-C.